# Is there a way to use the '+' operator as addition on parameters passed to a method as a generic type in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, addition

I recently discovered Scala, and I've written an RK4 solver that I'm trying to generalize as much as possible. After getting it working with arbitrarily large systems, I wanted to get it working with arbitrary numeric data types -but I've run into a wall. When I use a generic data type, no matter what restrictions I place on it, Scala automatically converts everything to strings to use '+'.

Most of what I've tried thus far has ultimately been writing the same thing in different ways. I could explicitly convert everything to the highest precision type I'll be using (BigDecimal) and call it a day, but that misses much of the point of generalizing the function.

This isn't my entire RK4 program, but it is the one piece of code I've been screwing with for the past couple hours:

```
def vecSum[T : Numeric]( u: Vector[T], v: Vector[T]): Vector[T] = (u, v).zipped.map(_ + _)
```

It's the vector sum (math vector, the data structure is just coincidental), which takes in two vectors and returns a single vector where each element is the sum of the two corresponding elements in the input vectors.

I'm trying to get it to return a vector of the same numeric type as the inputs, but it only wants to spit out a vector of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
  def vecSum[T](u: Vector[T], v: Vector[T])(implicit o: Numeric[T]): Vector[T] = (u, v).zipped.map((x, y) => o.plus(x, y))
```

If you specifically want to use `+` you can use

```
import Numeric.Implicits._
def vecSum2[T: Numeric](u: Vector[T], v: Vector[T]): Vector[T] = {
  (u, v).zipped.map((x, y) => x + y)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, both of those work perfectly!
I'm curious though: Why is the first one preferred?